# Extract a number from nvarchar column

Tags: oracle

Hoping you can help me. I have a column in a table called indicator. (Data type: `NVarchar(80)`)

Within this column I have some numbers the length of this number is 6 characters in length. The total the Length of indicator column can vary from 0 to 56 Characters long.

Below is small Subset of the data. What I would like to do is produce another column which extracts the numbers from indicator column.

```
Row 1 : GB-JP--123456
Row 2 : 401015 - GB-NA
Row 3 :
Row 4 : 999999 - LX - UK
```

I tried the following query but I get this error

```
select Substring (Indicator, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Indicator), LEN(Indicator)) from Table1
```

However I am presented with the following error

> "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier"

Comment: Oracle has no `patindex()` function

Answer (score 2):

> However I am presented with the following error
>
> "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier"

The provided query should be able to run, here is a test on [SQL Server 2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e52f7b89af6023ce92b6c2ac3261ca98)

**Unless** your tag is wrong and you are using `oracle`?

Then you would get an error like this:

> ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa9a498f9c5560e8cea5b85dd3f13fb1)

If that is the case, then you could use `regexp_replace` instead.

```
select regexp_replace(indicator, '[^0-9]', '') from table1
```

Resulting in

```
123456
401015

999999
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d2fb7516f8da18d3b381493978ab500d)

---

**Solution for SQL Server**

> Below is small Subset of the data. What I would like to do is produce
>   another column which extracts the numbers from indicator column.

If you want to get the numbers from the column **and** they are always one series of continuous numbers, you could do this

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING (Indicator, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Indicator), LEN(Indicator) )), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Indicator)), LEN(Indicator) ))
FROM table;
```

**Table & Data**

```
create table #temp
(
indicator nvarchar(80)
);

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('GB-JP--123456'),
('401015 - GB-NA'),
('1'),
('999999 - LX - UK');
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
123456
401015
1
999999
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=494a883e3d353c2b2fde36e9c40375c4)

**Remember** that due to using the `LEN()` function, trailing spaces are a potential issue.

```
INSERT INTO #temp
('1   ')
```

Returns an empty string when using above query.

`DATALENGTH()` can resolve this *(divided by `2` due to the `nvarchar` datatype, not that it really matters when using `SUBSTRING` like this*)

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING (Indicator, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Indicator),( DATALENGTH(Indicator)/2))), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Indicator)),( DATALENGTH(Indicator)/2) ))
from #temp;
```

[Comparison DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=267ca06b41e5f51f51a1ca8bf2f5cb0d)

Comment: @Masond3 well then check the answer for oracle: `select regexp_replace(indicator, '[^0-9]', '') from table1`

Comment: Hi @Randi- Thanks for sending this across. I am indeed using oracle. I transformed the query into the following ; 

SELECT
 REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(SUBSTR (Indicator, regexp_instr('%[0-9]%', Indicator), 
( LENGTH(Indicator)/2))), regexp_instr('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Indicator)),
( LENGTH(Indicator)/2) )) as A
 from #temp; however it only seems to extracting the text and not the #s

Updated code for oracle,

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can use the [TRANSLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690) function

```
select TRANSLATE(Indicator, '0123456789'||Indicator,'0123456789')
    from Table1
```

Digits are translated to digits, other characters of the column are removed.

From [Oracle SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690)

> TRANSLATE returns expr with all occurrences of each character in from_string replaced by its corresponding character in to_string. Characters in expr that are not in from_string are not replaced. The argument from_string can contain more characters than to_string. In this case, the extra characters at the end of from_string have no corresponding characters in to_string. If these extra characters appear in expr, then they are removed from the return value.
>
> If a character appears multiple times in from_string, then the to_string mapping corresponding to the first occurrence is used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Found i could do this way.

```
 SELECT 
indicator,
regexp_replace(indicator,'[^0-9]') as Numbers,
       regexp_replace(indicator, '[^a-z and ^A-Z]') as Characters
from temp
```